# How would you go about making this if else if program much more simplistic and less code redundant (C++)?

Tags: c++

Write a program that asks for the names of three runners and the time it took each
of them to finish a race. The program should display who came in first, second, and
third place.
Input Validation: Only accept positive numbers for the times.

**My Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string runner1, runner2, runner3;
    int time1, time2, time3;

    cout << "Please enter the names of three runners" << endl;
    cin >> runner1 >> runner2 >> runner3;
    cout << "How many minutes did it take " << runner1 << " to finish the race?" << endl;
    cin >> time1;
    cout << "How many minutes did it take " << runner2 << " to finish the race?" << endl;
    cin >> time2;
    cout << "How many minutes did it take " << runner3 << " to finish the race?" << endl;
    cin >> time3;

    if (time1 < time2 && time1 < time3)
    {
        cout << runner1 << " is 1st place!" << endl;

        if (time2 < time3)
        {
            cout << runner2 << " is 2nd place!" << endl;
            cout << runner3 << " is 3rd place!" << endl;
        }
        else if (time3 < time2)
        {
            cout << runner3 << " is 2nd place!" << endl;
            cout << runner2 << " is 3rd place!" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (time2 < time1 && time2 < time3)
    {
        cout << runner2 << " is 1st place!" << endl;

        if (time1 < time3)
        {
            cout << runner1 << " is 2nd place!" << endl;
            cout << runner3 << " is 3rd place!" << endl;
        }
        else if (time3 < time1)
        {
            cout << runner3 << " is 2nd place!" << endl;
            cout << runner2 << " is 3rd place!" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (time3 < time2 && time3 < time1)
    {
        cout << runner3 << " is 1st Place!" << endl;

        if (time2 < time1)
        {
            cout << runner2 << " is 2nd place!" << endl;
            cout << runner1 << " is 3rd place!" << endl;
        }
        else if (time1 < time2)
        {
            cout << runner1 << " is 2nd place!" << endl;
            cout << runner2 << " is 3rd place!" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error! Please restart the program and input a positive value" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program you show, does it *work*? Does it build? Does it run? Does it produce the expected results? Then what you want is a *code review* and you should post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Comment: @OP i'd start from improving code layout, so it would read better.

Comment: Since the question is written in the way it is, it sound like homework to me. So here are just a few hints: 1. Each runner has a corresponding time so it would make sense to bundle them together into a class or struct. 2. Member of this class could be made sortable by comparing their run time. 3. Sort them by storing them inside a STL container and sort them via `std::sort` (or something similar) 4. Print out who has one by iterating over the sorted container. Try it out and come back here if you have problems with that. SO ain't no code writing service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: While this isn't the _best_ question out there,  there is a good question hiding underneath this. The fundamental problem here is that there are 3!=6 branches, and this obviously doesn't scale.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the runners ordered in an array by their time, iterate over the runners array and output  (name + i + " place")

I think a linked list would be really good, but it might lose to a raw array if the runners don't change place very often or if there aren't many runners.

"Separate the drawing code from the game logic"

Your drawing code is cout calls. Your game logic is determining what place each runner is in. Then you draw based on that state that you calculated.

Your way is the most direct and fastest way to solve the problem of printing out runner places though.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Runner {
    int time;
    int id;

    int operator<(Runner runner) {
        return time < runner.time;
    }
};

char* pickSuffix(int place) {
    switch (place) {
    case 1:
        return "st";
    case 2:
        return "nd";
    case 3:
        return "rd";
    default:
        return "th";
    }
}

int main() {

    //make my runners, read in my times, runner 1 first
    Runner runners[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Enter runner " << i+1 << "'s time: ";
        cin >> runners[i].time;
        cout << endl;
        runners[i].id = i+1; //setup their id, used like a name
    }

    //figure out what place each runner came in
    //must overload operator< for object to use sort
    sort(runners, &runners[2]);

    //the position of the runner in the array is the place they came in
    //since it is sorted by their times
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Runner #" << runners[i].id << " came in " << i+1 << pickSuffix(i+1)  << " place!" << endl;
        cout << runners[i].time << endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample of the code written the way I described. I think for most purposes you wouldn't want to sort the runners in the array though, you would add a member variable `place` and just store their calculated position.

Comment: ＋1 for "Separate drawing from game logic". That's solid advice.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're beginning your journey in c++ programming. Welcome.

I'd seek to break the problem down into its component parts, so that we can end up expressing the intent of the solution in an easy-to-understand form:

```
int solve(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os) {

    Runners runners;
    collect_runners(os, is, runners);
    sort_by_time(runners);
    print_first_3(os, runners);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have not tied the solution to any particular input or output stream. That's so I can test it easily later.

Now that we have expressed the intent of the solution cleanly, we fill in the blanks (I have used various 'advanced' techniques that I hope you will find instructive and interesting).

I have used c++11.

Comments inline.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

/** The concept of coupling a runner's name with the time it took to run the race
 *
 */
struct Runner {
    std::string name;
    int time;
};

/** A collection of runners and their corresponding time.
 *
 */
using Runners = std::vector<Runner>;

/** Sort a container with a predicate. Return a reference to the container
 *
 * @tparam Container
 * @tparam Pred
 * @param c
 * @param pred
 * @return
 */
template<class Container, class Pred>
auto sort_container(Container &c, Pred &&pred) -> Container & {
    std::sort(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::forward<Pred>(pred));
    return c;
}

/** Sort a Runners array by ascending time
 *
 * @param vec
 * @return
 * */
Runners &sort_by_time(Runners &vec) {
    auto by_increasing_time = [](Runner const& l, Runner const& r) {
        return l.time < r.time;
    };

    sort_container(vec, by_increasing_time);
    return vec;
}

/** Print the first 3 runnes in an array of runners to an ostream
 *
 * @param os
 * @param vec
 */
void print_first_3(std::ostream& os, Runners const &vec) {
    static const char *nth[] = {
            "first",
            "second",
            "third"
    };

    auto limit = std::extent<decltype(nth)>::value;
    limit = std::min(limit, vec.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        auto const &runner = vec[i];
        os << runner.name << " is in " << nth[i] << " place with a time of " << runner.time << "\n";
    }
}

/** Ask a question on the console if the answer is to come from stdin
 *
 * @param is
 * @param q
 */
template<class Target>
void question(std::istream& is, Target& target, std::string const& q)
{
    if (std::addressof(is) == static_cast<std::istream*>(std::addressof(std::cin)))
    {
        std::cout << q << std::endl;
    }
    is >> target;
}

/** Build a runner using the supplied input and output streams
 *
 * @param os
 * @param is
 * @return
 */
Runner collect_runner(std::ostream& os, std::istream& is)
{
    Runner runner {};
    question(is, runner.name, "runner's name?");
    question(is, runner.time, "runner's time?");
    return runner;
}

/** Populate a Runners array using input and output streams
 *
 * @param os
 * @param is
 * @param runners
 * @return
 */
Runners& collect_runners(std::ostream& os, std::istream& is, Runners& runners)
{
    int nrunners = 0;
    question(is, nrunners, "how many runners?");

    while (nrunners-- > 0) {
        runners.push_back(collect_runner(os, is));
    }
    return runners;
}

/** Solve the problem at hand
 *
 * @param is
 * @param os
 * @return
 */
int solve(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os) {

    Runners runners;
    collect_runners(os, is, runners);
    sort_by_time(runners);
    print_first_3(os, runners);

    return 0;
}


/** Solve the problem using either std input/output or test input
 *
 * @param argc
 * @param argv
 * @note If argc == 2 and argv[1] == "test" then run solve using test input.
 *       We do this so that we can test our code without playing around with external files or
 *       the console each time we want to test it
 * @return
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 2 && argv[1] == std::string("test")) {
        static const char test_data[] = R"__(
5
bob 40
bill 20
sue 30
peter 25
zool 29
)__";
        std::istringstream test_stream{test_data};

        return solve(test_stream, std::cout);

    } else {

        return solve(std::cin, std::cout);
    }
}
```

test on the console with:

```
$ ./a.out test
```

expected output:

```
bill is in first place with a time of 20
peter is in second place with a time of 25
zool is in third place with a time of 29
```

Comment: Funny that `sort_container` implementation with more comments than code, trailing return, perfect forwarding etc. I was gonna post a competing sample in this comment, but found that I added some useful things, so upgrading to an answer...

Comment: @sehe two minds are better than one. Go for it. I wish I had someone here like you to help me write this rpc library instead of having to do it all alone...

Comment: Thank you. My answer is up :)

Answer (score 2):

I may have [laughed a little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963497/how-would-you-go-about-making-this-if-else-if-program-much-more-simplistic-and-l/44963612#comment76907449_44965420) at the complexity of Richard's answer.

He makes excellent points about organizing code, of course.

I end up posting my own review and a "simpler" sample, because I think the most important side of a program is **functionality**.

In this case,

- you need error handling (the user may enter illegal values)
- you need to check input (the user may enter more than 3 names, may enter identical names etc)
- you need to *properly* report ranks. If two runners had the same time, you will rank them in "arbitrary" order. You will want to correctly rate them as shared places.

My code

- is less tied to 3 runners (only when reading the three names, because that's what the sample required)
- <strike>exemplifies the use of `partial_sort` to get just the first 3 positions sorted</strike> That is no longer possible since the display function handles collections of unknown size and sharing places implies there maybe more than 3 ranked runners.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0f6d42cb829aa09)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

void static inline ignore_rest_of_line() {
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

struct Runner { 
    std::string name;
    int time = 0;

    bool operator<(Runner const& o) const { return time < o.time; }
};

std::vector<Runner> read_three() {
    std::string name1, name2, name3;
    auto unique = [&] { return std::set<std::string>{ name1, name2, name3 }.size() == 3; };

    std::cout << "Please enter the names of three runners\n";

    while (std::cin) {
        if (std::cin >> name1 >> name2 >> name3 && unique())
            break;
        std::cout << "Enter 3 unique names\n";
        ignore_rest_of_line();
    }

    ignore_rest_of_line();
    return { { name1, 0 }, { name2, 0 }, { name3, 0 } };
}

void read_time(Runner& runner) {
    while (std::cin) {
        std::cout << "How many minutes did it take " << runner.name << " to finish the race?\n";
        if ((std::cin >> runner.time) && runner.time > 0)
            break;
        std::cout << "Enter a valid time\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        ignore_rest_of_line();
    }

    ignore_rest_of_line();
}

template <typename List>
void display_winners(List runners) {
    std::sort(std::begin(runners), std::end(runners));

    std::string ranks[] = { "1st", "2nd", "3rd" };

    auto prev = runners.begin();
    auto rank = std::begin(ranks);

    for (auto& runner : runners) {
        if (runner.time != prev->time)
            ++rank;
        if (rank == std::end(ranks))
            break;
        std::cout << runner.name << " is " << *rank << " place\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cin.exceptions(std::ios::eofbit);
    auto runners = read_three();

    for (auto& runner : runners) {
        read_time(runner);
    }

    display_winners(runners);
}
```

The sample run shows

> Please enter the names of three runners
>   **a a b**
>   Enter 3 unique names
>   **a b c**
>   How many minutes did it take a to finish the race?
>   **9**
>   How many minutes did it take b to finish the race?
>   **invalid time 7**
>   Enter a valid time
>   How many minutes did it take b to finish the race?
>   **8**
>   How many minutes did it take c to finish the race?
>   **8**
>   c is 1st place
>   b is 1st place
>   a is 2nd place

Comment: I just realized my `partial_sort` is incorrect here in case the list is larger and there are many shared places (you might need to print more than 3 names, and they all should be in order). Fixed.

Comment: Do you remember that I agreed I would show you the way I do objects for asio? quick demo here: git@github.com:madmongo1/goblins.git

Comment: I do! I nearly missed this comment. Cloning the hell out of that quickly :)

Comment: I think it's worth noting that although Richard's answer is clearly *longer*, it's not really very complex. At first glance, it looks like its McCabe cyclomatic complexity (just to give one example) is 2. While it's possible to implement [non-trivial logic with a cyclomatic complexity of 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60102/489), most people find the result...a bit odd, at best.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It's all relative, and, relevantly, subjective to the pupil. But yeah, my answer didn't end up getting the complexity down. It did however get the input validation and logic up :) This was my point. I _intended_ to show a slimmed down version, but then I realized that the problem was underestimated (as always)